# Approach to loading forms and busy indicator

Tags: silverlight

I am "slowly" moving into Silverlight from asp.net and have a question about how to deal with  situation where some code needs to be executed after web service calls have completed. For example, when user clicks on the row in the data grid a dialog box is shown that allows editing of the record. It contains numerous combo boxes, check boxes etc. So I need to first load data for each of the combo boxes, and than when all finished loading, I need to set the bound entity. Since I am new to this async thing, I was thinking to have some kind of counter that will keep track on how many calls have been dispatched, and as they finish reduce them by one, until it is zero, at which point I could raise an event that load has finished,  and I could proceed with what ever is dependent on this. But this seems very clunky way of doing it. I am sure many have faced this issue, so how do you do this. If it helps, we use Prism with MVVM approach and Ria Services with Dtos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've described is pretty much the way to go. There may be more elegant things you can do with locks and mutexes, but your counter will work. It has the bonus that you can see how many operations are still "in progress" at any one time.

You could dispatch your events sequentially but that would defeat the whole purpose of asynchronous operations.

If you analysed what each part of your UI needs you might be able to do some operations before *all* of your async events have finished. Making sure you start the longest running operations first might help - but there's no guarantee that the other shorter operations will finish first. It all depends on what resources are available on both the client and server at the time the call is made.

Comment: I thought that there was some magic built into SL. Could "wait" and "async" from Async CTP be used for this?

Comment: @epitka - if there is I haven't found it yet. The Async CTP sounds like it might solve this sort of problem - but we've got a tight deadline to meet and as it's not v1.0 yet we can't use it. We should get to it in the New Year.